# Replace Jquery attr with quote doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, replace, attr

The below code works fine in FF but IE throws error because the onclick function contains quote in it. How to make this work in IE?

I'm doing something like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="add('1','val1')" id="link1">Link1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="add('2','val2')" id="link2">Link2</a>

<script>
function add(id,val) {
 //do something
 $('#link'+id).attr('onClick',$('#link'+id).attr('onClick').replace("add","remove"));
}

function remove(id,val) {
 //do something
 $('#link'+id).attr('onClick',$('#link'+id).attr('onClick').replace("remove","add"));
}
</script>
```

Example: After link1 is clicked the link should be updated to below

```
<a href="#" onclick="remove('1','val1')" id="link1">Link1</a>
```

Comment: Can you post what `onClick`'s value is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed onclick to href and voila it works in IE too.

Answer (score 0):

IE has issues with that, you could try using the [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method which works better in IE. However, you're always going to cause IE issues messing with changing event handlers.

It would be better to call the same function each time and just save a state somewhere on the page, even in an attribute such as toggling a the class between "add" and remove.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
var $link = $('#link');
var click = $link.attr('onClick');

$link.removeAttr('onClick');
$link.click(function() {
  eval(click.replace("XYZ","abc"));
});
```

But I strongly suggest you stop using `onClick` and start binding events with jQuery. If you could post the code in `onClick`, I could convert it into standard jQuery objects and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's helps:

```
function add(id,val) {

 $('#link'+id).attr('onClick',function (i, click) {
                    var str = new String(click);
                    return str.replace("add","remove");
                });
}
```